# Is this poorly formed JSON?

Tags: json, swift5, codable

I am working through an online tutorial that makes use of the Whitehouse Petitions JSON feed.  I am using Swift 5 and have implemented my structs to conform to Codable.  The Whitehouse JSON causes a Codable error.  Below is a snippet of the JSON.  The part that is causing trouble is "response".  In the first example it is shown like I would expect an empty array to be, but when it has a value as in the second example, the JSON switches from [] to {} as shown below.

[ ] example:

```
  "results":[
      {
         "id":"2722358",
         "type":"petition",
         "title":"Remove Chuck Schumer and Nancy Pelosi from office",
         "body":"Schumer and Pelosi's hatred and refusing to work with...",
         "petition_type":[
          {
              "id":291,
              "name":"Call on Congress to act on an issue"
          }
        ],
        "signatureThreshold":100000,
        "status":"closed",
        "response":[

        ],
        "created":1547050064,
        "isSignable":false,
        "isPublic":true,
        "reachedPublic":0
       },
```

{ } Example

```
  "results":[
  {
     "id":"2722358",
     "type":"petition",
     "title":"Remove Chuck Schumer and Nancy Pelosi from office",
     "body":"Schumer and Pelosi's hatred and refusing to work with...",
     "petition_type":[
      {
          "id":291,
          "name":"Call on Congress to act on an issue"
      }
    ],
    "signatureThreshold":100000,
    "status":"closed",
    "response":{
         "id":2630367,
         "url":"https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/response/response-your-petition-3",
    },
    "created":1547050064,
    "isSignable":false,
    "isPublic":true,
    "reachedPublic":0
   },
```

From what I can tell from my research of the issue, JSON should be written consistently.  In other words, since "response" is never an array, but just a single value then it should have been written as { } instead of [ ] when empty.  Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: Hmm.  It calls it valid.  Even with one shown as [ ]  and one shown as { } with stuff in it.  Codable throws an error basically saying expected Array though.

Comment: Thanks @dratenik.  I cut the body down down here just for readability and forgot to add the quotes back.

Comment: And, as always I appreciate the down vote...not sure why I come back to this site.

Comment: Both those JSONs are probably fine, but as `[]` and `{...}` are different things, you will probably not be able to load both using one Codable definition.

Comment: Yeah, that is the same conclusion that I came to, but was hoping for a Stack Overflow miracle.  I am unclear why they chose to switch them up like that.

Comment: Not sure if this would help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52681385/swift-codable-multiple-types

Comment: here's another article: https://medium.com/@sajjadsarkoobi/support-multiple-types-in-codable-swift-de461689e21b

Comment: Alternatively you could pre-process the input to conform to what you want from it. Bash it into shape with a regex replacement?

Comment: "The downside of using Codable is that you can't encode and decode properties where the type is mixed or unknown, for example [String: Any], [Any] or Any. These are sometimes a neccessary evil in many apis, and AnyCodable makes supporting these types easy." https://github.com/yonaskolb/Codability#any-codable

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an empty array only when there is not value for `response` property, you can make `response` property optional, then implement the decoding and catch the `DecodingError.typeMismatch` error like this:

```
struct Results: Decodable {
    let results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let type: String
    let title: String
    let body: String
    let petition_type: [PetitionType]
    let signatureThreshold: Int
    let status: String
    let response: Response?
    let created: Date
    let isSignable: Bool
    let isPublic: Bool
    let reachedPublic: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case type
        case title
        case body
        case petition_type
        case signatureThreshold
        case status
        case response
        case created
        case isSignable
        case isPublic
        case reachedPublic
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        body = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .body)
        petition_type = try container.decode([PetitionType].self, forKey: .petition_type)
        signatureThreshold = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .signatureThreshold)
        status = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .status)
        
        do {
            response = try container.decode(Response.self, forKey: .response)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            response = nil
        }
        
        created = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .created)
        isSignable = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isSignable)
        isPublic = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isPublic)
        reachedPublic = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .reachedPublic)
    }
}

struct PetitionType: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct Response: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let url: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just create a decoding wrapper:

```
struct InvalidDecodableWrapper<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let value: T?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let container = try? decoder.singleValueContainer() else {
            value = nil
            return
        }

        value = try container.decode(T.self)
    }
}
```

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let url: String
}

struct Result: Decodable {    
    ...
    let response: InvalidDecodableWrapper<Response>
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses.  I found the solution that worked for me
[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58359549/decode-data-that-could-change-at-times?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I created a new struct:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var url: String
}
```

Then created an extension of my Petition struct:

```
struct Petition {
    var title: String
    var body: String
    var signatureCount: Int
    var signatureThreshold: Int
    var signaturesNeeded: Int
    var status: String
    var response: [Response]
    var issues: Array<Issue>
 }

extension Petition: Codable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        body  = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .body)
        signatureCount = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .signatureCount)
        signatureThreshold = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .signatureThreshold)
        signaturesNeeded = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .signaturesNeeded)
        status = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .status)
        do {
            response = try [container.decode(Response.self, forKey: .response)]
        } catch {
            response = try container.decode([Response].self, forKey: .response)
        }
        issues = try container.decode([Issue].self, forKey: .issues)
    }
}
```

The result is that I end up with an empty array, or an array with a single Response struct that I am able to access correctly.  So in my viewController I simply check if response.count > 0 and if so it is safe to access response[0].url etc...